# How do I remove the "number/hash/pound/#" sign from the destination rewrite URL in Helicon ISAPI Rewrite?

Tags: url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, helicontech, urlrewriting.net

I have the following rewrite rule set up:

RewriteRule /ProductF12.aspx$ /womens-jackets/l/20 [I,O,RP,L]

**Problem:**

When someone hits:

**/ProductF12.aspx?ProductId=7814&lang=en&colour=950%7C666666&mc=yes#sthash.oYnetaAi.qjtu**

It goes to:

**/womens-jackets/l/20#sthash.oYnetaAi.qjtu**

Question: As you can see, the Query string is removed but everything after the "**#**" sign remains.

How do I remove the extra  **#sthash.oYnetaAi.qjtu** from the destination URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of URL starting with # does not come to the server but is set by browser, that's why ISAPI_Rewrite can do nothing about it.

Comment: I was afraid of that :(. Bad news but thank you for the answer.